# В режиме Pose Mode кости отходят от привязанных к нему вершин

Tags: blender

Попытался привязать выделенные вершины к соответствующим группам вершин, но **при передвижении костей** (модель привязана к кости; меш - потомок арматуры) **в Pose Mode кость начинает отходить всё дальше от группы** по мере передвижения курсором, хотя до этого всё было нормально: кости следовали строго за группой вершин. **Также, во время работы в Pose Mode, при вращении костей модель начинает** не только вращаться, но и **искажаться**; последнее не должно быть. Что я сделал не так, и как сделать так, чтобы модель снова следовала за костями.

Скриншоты: прилагаются к этому вопросу. Сравнил две модели между собой (1 - которая с указанной проблемой выше; 2 - полностью исправная; именно так кости должны вести при передвижении/вращении в Pose Mode).

Видео: [*кликабельно*](https://youtu.be/IIyKxsWb_nY). Сравнил две модели между собой (1 - которая с указанной проблемой выше; 2 - полностью исправная; именно так кости должны вести при передвижении/вращении в Pose Mode).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/NQTsHLY8WTyh9g